# How to add data in site on Runtime with kotlin?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin

Can anyone please tell me that if we have multiple tables in sqlite and and we want to add data in specific table which users enter for example , we have "Home" , "Market" and "Office" table and each table have two fieid text and image now user will enter text , image and table name , If user enter Office then Text and image will be added to office table and so on  How ??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created hree tables "Home" , "Office" and "Market" with two input feilds "text" and "Image" , and take image , text and Table name from user after that apply if condition that if Table name == Home then add it to home table and so on